# SPGridView SelectedRow.Cells[] returns empty value

Tags: 2010, visual-web-part, event-handlers, spgridview

I have created an SPGridView control in my visual web part. Inside SPGridView, there is an SPHyperLink control that stores some URL. **When accessing this value using SPGridView SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text, i am getting an empty value.**

**SPGridView Control**

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="ShowNode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AllowSorting="true" OnRowDataBound="ShowNode_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNode_RowIndexChanged" OnSorting="ShowNode_Sort" OnRowCommand="ShowNode_RowClick">
<Columns>
<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Icon"  DataImageUrlField="Img" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"></asp:ImageField>
<SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Title" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Name"/>
<SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Type" />
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>
</Columns>
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

**Row Click event**

```
protected void ShowNode_RowIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int ind = ShowNode.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
            string link = ShowNode.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;


        }
```

Comment: At which event you are trying to access the value? On OnSelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: @Aanchal Yes. This is the event - OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNode_RowIndexChanged"

Comment: when should it be fired?

Comment: @Gwny It triggers when a GridView row item is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the values using SPGridView DataKey attribute.

**GridView Control**

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="ShowNode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" ShowFooter="true"  ShowHeader="true" DataSourceID="" DataKeyNames="Link,Type" OnRowDataBound="ShowNode_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNode_RowIndexChanged" OnSorting="ShowNode_Sort"  EnableViewState="true" >

<Columns>

<asp:ImageField HeaderText="Icon"  DataImageUrlField="Img" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">

</asp:ImageField><SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="Name"/>

<SharePoint:SPBoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"  />

<asp:HyperLinkField  DataTextField="Link" HeaderText="Link" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"/>

</Columns> 

</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
string u= ShowNode.DataKeys[ShowNode.SelectedRow.RowIndex]["Link"].ToString(); 

string t = ShowNode.DataKeys[ShowNode.SelectedRow.RowIndex]["Type"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "Visible=false" property from hyperlink field and then check, it should not return empty value then.

I am getting value on my side. Try to debug it and see in window "Shift+F9"
Navigate there as this will help you to find value of a particular control.

Comment: Thanks. But i am getting empty value for other controls too. So visibility is not a factor.